# Why does visual studios .csproj.FileListAbsolute generation behave erratically

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

Bit involved and wordy, I apologise.

Background: I have been working on a number of visual studio MVC projects in which intellisense was not working correctly for view specific commands (notably ViewBag and EditorFor templates taking lambda expresions)
After hunting around I found the following solution [here](http://mhammadchehab.com/wordpress/2013/12/enabling-intellisense-for-razor-in-class-library-mvc-5-razor-3-0/)
Since the solution didn't explain why the problem occurred or how the steps resolved it and that I didn't want to have to manually do this for dozens of projects, I have investigated the behind the scenes changes.

The problem comes down to the .csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt in the obj folder not including lines for copying referenced dll's correctly when the output directory is set to a folder outside of the solutions. Once it is created (either by hand or by changing the output directory to bin\ and rebuilding) visual studio does not remove the references - so far.

What I would like to know is:
How VS decides what to put in to that file so I can automate a fix which doesn't involve my commiting all the obj files to source control
OR
How to tell VS what to put in that file in a way etc etc.

I hope this is clear enough but if not I will be happy to answer questions.